# When i pass this value to comments param, to api. Getting 403 forbidded in postman and web browser

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, postman, xss, http-status-code-403

`"comments": "jdfjdskf  <script>sss</script>",`

this param is available in my post request body. If I change any other value except `<Script>` it is working fine.

For Ex: if I pass `<p>` tag, it is working fine

otherwise getting 403 forbidden, no Nginx logs also catched. There is no `.htaccess` or Nginx configuration is there.

If it is xss script preventing mechanism it should block all html tags right.

Comment: Not sure what the question is here... sounds like a question for the maintainer of the API? "If it is xss script preventing mechanism it should block all html tags right." - not necessarily.

Comment: "If it is xss script preventing mechanism it should block all html tags right.",

- Yes, but it is allowing other html tags, even if did some spelling mistake in </script> as </scrpt> it is allowing. 

while doing testing in api we found this

Comment: _"If it is xss script preventing mechanism it should block all html tags right."_ - why? The second "S" in "XSS" stands for Scripting. A naked `p` element without any `onxyz` event handler attributes, and whatever else might lead to script execution, would be quite "harmless" in that regard ... whereas a `script` element is likely to contain executable code in most cases.